# WP7 UIElement property bound to an ObservableCollection isn't updated when an item is added or removed from the ObservableCollection

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, observablecollection, uielement

In the following code: a `UIElement` bound to an `ObservableCollection` does not update when items are added or removed from the collection.

Specifically:

A Person object includes an `ObservableCollection` property, Links, which can contain any number of Link objects which can refer to other Person objects.
The Person and Link classes both implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    // fields
    private string id = "";
    private string firstName = "";
    private string lastName = "";
    private Links links = new Links();

    // properties firing PropertyChanged events 
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.id)
            {
                this.id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.firstName)
            {
                this.firstName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.lastName)
            {
                this.lastName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
    }
    public Links Links
    {
        get { return links; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.links)
            {
                this.links = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Links");
            }
        }
    }

    // constructors
    public Person()
    {
        new Person("", "", "");
    }
    public Person(string id, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

}



public enum LinkState { none, oneway, twoway }

public class Link: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    // fields
    private Person fromWhom;
    private Person toWhom;

    // properties firing PropertyChanged events 
    public Person FromWhom
    {
        get { return fromWhom; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.fromWhom)
            {
                this.fromWhom = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FromWhom");
            }
        }
    }
    public Person ToWhom
    {
        get { return toWhom; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.toWhom)
            {
                this.toWhom = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ToWhom");
            }
        }
    }

    // constructors
    public Link()
    {
        new Link(null, null);
    }
    public Link(Person fromWhom, Person toWhom)
    {
        this.FromWhom = fromWhom;
        this.ToWhom = toWhom;
    }

}
```

The Links and Crowd classes are both subclasses of ObservableCollections. A Crowd object is an ObservableCollection of Person objects. A Links object is an ObservableCollection of Link objects:

```
 public class Links: ObservableCollection<Link>
    {

    }


    public class Crowd : ObservableCollection<Person>
    {

    }
```

The MainPage class of the WP7 application is a subclass of the PhoneApplicationPage class.
It contains two properties:
Crowd, a Crowd object and
Me, a Person object.

The following XAML is supposed to display:
a) The number of links from the Me object to the Person objects in the Crowd, and
b) A list of the Person objects in the Crowd.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Name="ThePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PersonLink"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    x:Class="PersonLink.MainPage"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ThePage, Path=Crowd}">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:LinksToCountConverter x:Key="linkCount" />
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ElementName=ThePage, Path=Me.FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock  Text=" has " />
                <TextBlock x:Name=LinkCounter  Text="{Binding ElementName=ThePage, Path=Me.Links,Converter={StaticResource linkCount}}" />
                <TextBlock  Text=" links." />
            </StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ID}" />
                            <TextBlock  Text=" " />
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <TextBlock  Text=" " />
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                            <local:LinkButton Content="Link" Click="LinkButton_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

HOWEVER, when Link objects are added or removed from Me.Links (an ObserverableCollection) the Textblock named "LinkCounter" doesn't update, even though its bound to the ObservableCollection.

Since the Me.Links ObservableCollection is changed when a new Link is added to it, or an existing Link is removed from, I thought that anything bound to it should update.

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The databinding won't be triggered here as you are not changing the reference to the Links collection. Instead of binding to the reference and using a converter try using

```
<TextBlock x:Name=LinkCounter  Text="{Binding ElementName=ThePage, Path=Me.Links.Count" />
```

Comment: The suggestion causes an exception -- (because Count is a method?). This is why I used a Converter in the original code.

Comment: Addendum. Sorry, after changing the another line regarding the DataContext, the suggestion worked.  I guess this is because the value of Links.Count changes when items are added or removed from the Links collection.  That makes sense, but the documentation says that a CollectionChanged event is fired whenever items are removed or added.  Why isn't a reference to Me.Links therefore triggered.  And  here's a related question,  I'd like to examine the Link objects in the Links collection whenever their count changes.  Do I pass Links into a Converter as a parameter?